# paypal NVP TransactionSearch error message "The number of results were truncated"

Tags: php, paypal, nvp

The title is the Paypal NVP API's error message. API is `TransactionSearch`. 
In my PHP code, if I set the search parameters `"STATUS" => "Reversed"`, The API return this result:

> ```
> 'TIMESTAMP' => '2016-03-23T02:32:41Z',
> 'CORRELATIONID' => '77fcf63ee550e',
> 'ACK' => 'SuccessWithWarning',
> 'VERSION' => '109.0',
> 'BUILD' => '18316154',
> 'L_ERRORCODE0' => '11002',
> 'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Search warning',
> 'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The number of results were truncated. Please change your search parameters if you wish to see all your results.',
> 'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Warning'
> ```

But, If I not add the search parameters `"STATUS"`, API return success!

so, I want to know how to set search parameters that I can get right result with `"STATUS" => "Reversed"`

Answer (score 1):

do you have many reversed transactions? I ask because the maximum number of transactions that can be returned from a TransactionSearch API call is 100. In this case looks like the API response has more than 100 hits. Try to reduce the data range or look for other status and see if you still get the error. Anyway here you can find the technical reference guide for this API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/